# Generate 10 random no's and display the length of the longest increasing series in java without using array or anything

Tags: java

```
class IncreasingSeries {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int no, i, max = 0, counter = 0, temp = 0;
        System.out.println("Generated values are : ");
        //Random Numbers are generated and checked.
        for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            no = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
            System.out.print(no + " ");
            if (no > max) {
                max = no;
                counter++;
            } else {
                if (temp < counter) temp = counter;
                max = 0;
                counter = 1;
            }
        }
        if (counter >= temp) System.out.println("\n The length of the longest increasing series is " + counter);
        else System.out.println("\n The length of the longest increasing series is " + temp);
    }
}
```

In some of the values the answers is correct but for some values the output is 1 more the actual answer.
for ex:
99,87,25,6,57,29,40,29,4,37. The output should be 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies at the place where you reset `max`. When you see a number that is lower than the current `max`, you should set it as the current max and then reset the counter:

```
        else {
            if(temp<counter)
                temp=counter;
            max=no; // <-- this line is changed!
            counter=1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can use the following code, which using three variables to track the state. The random number r is checked against the last number generated and if it is greater than or equal to the last random, increaseCount is incremented by 1. We also use another variable maxIncrease to store the maximum out of all increaseCount streaks. If the random number is less than the last number, we reset increase count.

```
    int maxIncrease = 0;
    int increaseCount = 0;
    int last = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int r = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
        System.out.println(r);
        if (r >= last) {
            increaseCount++;
            if(increaseCount > maxIncrease)
                maxIncrease = increaseCount;
            last = r;
        } else {
            increaseCount = 0;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Max streak was: " + maxIncrease);
```